# Element ui el-cascader cascade selector secondary list drop-down scroll to load more data

Tags: element-ui

The data of the first-level list will be obtained normally at one time. Now I want to realize the drop-down scroll loading of the second-level list. When I write by myself, I use lazy lazy loading, but I don't know how to add the new data obtained by the drop-down scroll. I can't actively call lazyload. Then I simply use options

What should I do?What should I do?What should I do?